# Export ICNS icon from Adobe Illustrator

Tags: macos, format, adobe-illustrator, icns

I have create an icon in Adobe Illustrator (CS6) for my own Mac OS X application. How can I export the icon the Apple's .icns icon format? The .icns file should contain the icon in multiple resolutions.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a simple but yet nice working export script for Adobe Illustrator. Since I only posses CS6 I could only test it with that version. You find it at https://github.com/choffmeister/adobe-illustrator-icnsexport. Contribution is very welcome.